# How is there a bijection between an infinite set and a proper subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that there cannot be a bijection between $S$, a finite set, and $S'$, a proper subset of $S$, because $S'$ will contain at least one fewer item than $S$.

What I don't understand is the definition of an infinite set, [a set for which there is a bijection between itself and a proper subset of itself](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteSet.html).

Take the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, which is infinite. Then isn't the set $A$ $=$ { 1, 2, 3 } a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ yet not a bijection of $\mathbb{N}$? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The condition is that there is *some* proper subset of $S$ in bijection with $S$. Of course, your example $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is finite and so it admits no bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. But $\mathbb{N}$ has many subsets to which it admits a bijection. One natural choice is the set $\{2, 4, 6, \ldots\}$ of positive even numbers, for which a natural bijection is given by doubling each number, i.e., $n \mapsto 2 n$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the proper subset can also be infinite.

Example:

$$2\mathbb{Z} \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}$$
One bijection is
$$
\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to 2\mathbb{Z}
$$
given by
$$
\phi(x) = 2x.
$$